# AngularJS app not called

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello I have tried many ways to initialize a basic app but I do not know what it is wrong. The logic is the following

I "append" the following html containing the angular js module using a jquery ajax call.

```
('submit', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: form.attr('method'),
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                result.html(data);
```

Then the following html is loaded together with angularjs and the script having the module and controller definitions

HTML:

Load angular.js and the script where angular app is defined
I type data-ng-app="app" in Body, HTML or wherever
then data-ng-controller="controller" in a div or wherever i want to work on with the scope. Which should be already enough to initialize the controller. Am I right?

SCRIPT:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('controller', ["$scope", "$http", function ($scope,$http) {

    console.log('works');

    ...more stuffs
]);
```

I have tried to copy paste from the most basics examples in tutorials but still not working. No problems with dependencies or syntax errors.
What can be the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You will need to add some more of your code that will allow someone to reproduce it in a minimal way.

Comment: Add your html complete please

Comment: you would immediately see problems with this code just by running it and opening the console!

Comment: Could be that the whole html is comes from a jquery Ajax call?

Comment: You can take this demo as a reference, it has the same problem https://plnkr.co/edit/FFjoTen5fZhptNfaV0wq?p=preview

Comment: All relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem must be in the question itself, not some third-party website. It would be preferable for you to post a [mcve]. See [ask] for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue i see with your code is you are not passing the dependencies to your function

```
app.controller("listController", ["$scope", "$http"
    function($scope,$http) {         
         console.log('works');         
}]);
```

[**DEMO APP**](https://plnkr.co/edit/FFjoTen5fZhptNfaV0wq?p=preview)

Comment: sorry i missed that. it is there

Comment: Check the demo link I added

Comment: the angular app is loaded correctly but the controller is not initialized